# Framework 'Flutter' not found - While build iOS app

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode

Failed to build iOS app
Error (Xcode): Framework 'Flutter' not found

Error (Xcode): Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple reasons for this rejection you need to try the following different ways

1.

- Firstly, Deintegrate all the pods
- Please delete Runner.xcworkspace before installing pods
- Install the Pods after doing flutter clean && flutter pub get

2. 

- You can try by uncommenting this in podfile (# platform :ios, '11.0')

Please let me know if you have any confusion on the above provided code

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your pod file:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = "12.0"
     end
  end
end
```